# Track Mouse-Click on MS-Word for a customized Addon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, mouseevent

I am developing a Word Add-on, in which I have to track the **Click** event on every user-control (e.g Tabs, Buttons,.etc)  and then write some Code based on that event, How to do this using C# ?

PS: More Precisely, user-controls include the Ribbon and different controls on the Ribbon.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the Word object library. To do this, follow these steps:
On the Project menu, click Add Reference.
On the COM tab, locate Microsoft Word 11.0 Object Library

for reference You can go through this link [MSWord](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302817)

i havent tried for ms word i have worked with outlook in the same way.

```
private Word.ApplicationClass oWord;

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //===== Create a new document in Word ==============
    // Create an instance of Word and make it visible.
    oWord = new Word.ApplicationClass();
    oWord.Visible = true;

    // Local declarations.
    Word._Document oDoc;
    Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    // Add a new document.
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing,ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing,ref oMissing); // Clean document

    // Add text to the new document.
    oDoc.Content.Text = "Handle Events for Microsoft Word Using C#.";
    oDoc = null;        

    //============ Set up the event handlers ===============

    oWord.DocumentBeforeClose += 
        new Word.ApplicationEvents3_DocumentBeforeCloseEventHandler( 
        oWord_DocumentBeforeClose );  
    oWord.DocumentBeforeSave += 
        new Word.ApplicationEvents3_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler( 
        oWord_DocumentBeforeSave );  
    oWord.DocumentChange += 
        new Word.ApplicationEvents3_DocumentChangeEventHandler( 
        oWord_DocumentChange );
    oWord.WindowBeforeDoubleClick += 
        new Word.ApplicationEvents3_WindowBeforeDoubleClickEventHandler( 
        oWord_WindowBeforeDoubleClick );
    oWord.WindowBeforeRightClick +=
        new Word.ApplicationEvents3_WindowBeforeRightClickEventHandler( 
        oWord_WindowBeforeRightClick );
}

// The event handlers.

private void oWord_DocumentBeforeClose(Word.Document doc, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(
        "DocumentBeforeClose ( You are closing " + doc.Name + " )");
}

private void oWord_DocumentBeforeSave(Word.Document doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(
        "DocumentBeforeSave ( You are saving " + doc.Name + " )");
}

private void oWord_DocumentChange()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("DocumentChange");
}

private void oWord_WindowBeforeDoubleClick(Word.Selection sel, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(
        "WindowBeforeDoubleClick (Selection is: " + sel.Text + " )");
}

private void oWord_WindowBeforeRightClick(Word.Selection sel, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(
        "WindowBeforeRightClick (Selection is: " + sel.Text + " )");

}
```

Comment: Here u will not able to get each and every event please go through this link to know which events we can get `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application_events(v=office.14).aspx`

Comment: Did you mean, they are obscured by Microsoft from being tracked ?

Comment: Yeah they haven't exposed each and every events.we can track new document, open previous document,document closed,document saved,DocumentChange etc,.

Comment: I don't think so, Even I had tracked several events which ain't mentioned in [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302817) e.g., `copy`, `cut` etc,. using `idmso` but I am not able to track all of them.

Comment: Any further suggesstions @Ravi

Comment: Give me some Time even iam looking into it dude.:)